# Chrome extension background.html not logging to console

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm having trouble getting my content script to communicate with my background page. I'm running an unpacked extension. In my content script `send.js` I have a line

`chrome.extension.sendRequest({message: "hey"}, function(response){});`

and my `background.html` looks like:

```
<script>
/* the coffeescript way, but I also tried without the 
 * coffeescript wrappers and got the same errors. */
(function() {
  var dispatchRequest;
  dispatchRequest = function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log("request dispatch called");
  }
  chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(dispatchRequest);
}).call(this);
</script>
```

I keep getting a `Port error: Could not establish connection` error.

Just to try to find the error I changed my `background.html` to

```
<script>
console.log("Background html is running!");
</script>
```

I then reloaded the page and checked the Chrome console but there was no output.

Here's my (abbreviated) `manifest.json`:

```
{
   "background-page": "background.html",
   "content_scripts": [{
      "all_frames": true                      ,
      "css": [ "style.css" ]                  ,
      "js": [ "send.js" ]                     ,
      "matches": [ "http://mail.google.com/*" ,
                   "https://mail.google.com/*" ]
    }],
    "permissions": [ "tabs", "http://*/", "https://*/", "cookies" ]
}
```

At this point I'm at a loss to figure out how to get the `background.html` to run or how to get my content script to communicate with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming it's not just a transcription error, the manifest key for the background page should be `background_page`, not `background-page`.

Comment: Note that this is old, the newer way is to use `"background": { "page": "background.html"}`